# Install FTP application FileZilla Server on your Virtual Machine VM and Publish using FTP

Tags: azure, ftp, filezilla

On your Virtual machine VM, Here is the correct install of the FileZilla server application? and then how to publish your website throw it to your VM?
How to open the ports on Azure for FTP FileZilla Server and how to connect it?

Comment: Did it work or not?

Comment: Yes, as below description.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Download "FileZilla Server" on your azure VM (Virtual machine); The download link is available here:

http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server

Now install it, And follow these steps:

1- Go with default setting as below

[image]

2- Choose the default "Install as a service, Start with windows", And make the port 14147

3- After finish installation, the FileZilla will run and popup this screen for you, fill it as in image:
[image]

4- Now we want to locate the folder for the FTP process, But before that we need to add a group and a user; So, from the menu go to "Edit" --> "Groups" and add a Group, then the shared folder as below :

[image]

- Add full permission to the group on selected folder.

5- Edit --> Users as below :
[image]
[image]

6- Now, Go to Edit --> Settings :

Go to "Passive mode settings", and fill as below:
[image]

7- Then go to tab "FTP Over TLS Settings" and create a certificate as below:
[image]

8- Now, we have to open the ports on VM Windows Firewall :
[image]
[image]
Add these ports: 14147 , 21 and 990:
[image]
Then Choose the default option to allow all connection and give a name for these ports.

9- Go to "Outbound Rules" and choose Add new rules, follow the same steps in point 8 and be sure to choose "Allow the Connections" and not the default one which is "Block Connections".

10- Now we need to open the ports on Azure portal page:

Log to https://portal.azure.com and then select your VM and then follow these steps:
"Network Interfaces" -- > "Network security Group" --> "Inbound Security Rule"
And add the ports 21, 14147 and 990 one after each other as below:
[image]

- Don't forget to repeat above image step for other ports.
  11- Do the same with Outbound Security Rules, with all ports 21, 14147 and 990:
  [image]

12- To publish your site on FTP, Follow these steps :
a. After Open your project on Visual Studio, Right click on your project, the select "Publish".
b. [image]
c. [image]
d. Validate your connection.
e. Next --> Next --> Publish your website.

Comment: Bashar Abu Shamaa - Bashar, I am following all steps and I am not able to connect from outside the box to my file zilla server. Do you know if we need to do anything additional to what you have listed above? thanks!

Comment: I can understand 21 is for ftp protocol, 14747 is for admin, but what is port 990 for? in my VM, I don't have to let the firewall allow 990, still works.